# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Tab count: 2

Tags: java, exception

I am trying delete a tab from my tabs. When I add 2 or more tabs simultaneously then delete the first added tabs, the result is an exception. why?

Code in Adding Tab:

```
     String name4 = "Untitled" + jTabbedPane2.getTabCount();
   name3=new JLabel("Untitled" + jTabbedPane2.getTabCount());
   pnlTab = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
   text=new JTextArea();
    text.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    text.setLineWrap(true);
    text.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 72));


    pnlTab.setOpaque(false);
    button = new JButton("X");
    button.setForeground(Color.red);
   
   gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
  gbc.gridx = 0;
  gbc.gridy = 0;
  gbc.weightx = 0;


     pnlTab.add(name3, gbc);

   gbc.gridx++;
   gbc.weightx = 0;
   pnlTab.add(button, gbc);


    jTabbedPane2.addTab(null, text);
    
    jTabbedPane2.setTabComponentAt(jTabbedPane2.getTabCount()-1, pnlTab);
```

Code in deleting tab:

```
    private void jTabbedPane2MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    int index = jTabbedPane2.getSelectedIndex();
    
     button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jTabbedPane2.remove(index); 
           
        }

      });
    
   }
```

Why is the result is :

```
     Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Tab 
   count: 2
```

Comment: The message tells you the problem. You only have 2 tabs, so you can only delete index 0 or 1. We can't tell you were the problem is.

Comment: @camickr what do you think is the solution here? My problem is when i add two tabs and delete the first one, i get an exception

Comment: I just told you. The index is wrong. Do some debugging to determine why you think the index is 2. If you want to remove a tab you should get the currently selected index in the actionPerformed() method of the button. Don't set the index variable in advance.

Comment: *delete the first one, i get an exception* - so the index should be 0, not 2.  Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. So you need your frame with a tabbed pane and two tabs and your delete button. The entire class should be about 20 - 30 lines of code. Once you get this simple example working, then you figure out the problem with your real code. We should be able to copy/paste/compile and test this simple class to see the described problem. Chances are while you create the MRE you will find your problem.

Comment: I have used a JFrame form in netbeans. Its complicated

Comment: That is the point of the [mre], to uncomplicate your code so you can see where you are making your mistake.